# "Increase" or "decrease" in a between-subject design

Tags: statistics

This is actually about scientific writing (and I'm not sure which Exchange site I should ask), a very simple one.

There are some group-wise comparisons in data analysis (in general), and in some cases, it is impossible to change group assignment. For example, you can put someone in a real drug group or a placebo group. But you cannot put someone in a male group or a female group. Then in this case, if you find a significant group difference, does it sound okay for you to say "increase" or "decrease" in that statistic? I find it very strange and think it's wrong because the condition (or explanatory variable) cannot be changed, so I have been avoiding using 'increase/decrease' for group-wise statistics.

But (obviously) I'm not a native English speaker nor a highly experienced reader. So I wonder how the native writers think, and why they keep using 'increase' for group differences.

Answer (score 0):

In the specific case where the grouping variable is categorical, it is only very slightly clunky but it makes sense and is just fine.  It sounds a bit smoother to use something like 'greater' in that case.  For example you might want to say:

> The average effect for the female group was X.  When looking at the
>   male group, the average effect increased to Y.

But you probably would be slightly better off to say:

> The average salary for the female group was X.  When looking at the
>   male group, the average effect, Y, was greater.

If the grouping variable in question is numeric and you use 'increase' or 'decrease' to describe it, then describing the metric with 'increase' or 'decrease' also sounds just fine.  E.g.:

> As height increased, X decreased.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry that I just checked your answer. Yes, it appears so because many (almost) papers write something like "we found increased X in the group A compared to the group B". But I still think that it is technically incorrect when you use "increase" or "decrease" for results from a between-subject design. But I also write time to time when "an increase in X" sounds better than "the larger X". Is there such an abstract word for "larger-ness" or "greater-ness" that I can use instead?